# Looping through game objects on a Node.js + websocket server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket

Based on my research, websockets are a reliable way for sending data rapidly between client and server because there is no HTTP overhead.

The socket.io example shows logic happening only during socket messaging:

https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/blob/master/examples/chat/index.js

In a real-time game, logic needs to happen outside of socket connections eg. to move monsters, projectiles, run down timers etc.

I imagine that any good solution for 1 game instance would work well for multiple game instances.

Maybe Node.js `async.each()` and `async.parallel()` will work?

I'd like to keep a consistent internal clock or "frame" rate for updating the game logic.

On clientside, I can use

```
loop() {
    this.now = Date.now();
    var delta  = this.now - this.last;
    this.last = this.now;

    this.dt = this.dt + delta;

    if (this.dt < this.rate) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
        return;
    } else {
        this.game.loop();
        this.draw();
        this.dt = this.dt - this.rate;
    }

    this.game.loopKeyboardInput(this.key_pressed_map);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(this.loop.bind(this));
}
```

for tracking delta time.

How can I do something similar on a server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something simple like this runs the game loop method asynchronously, allowing the server to update the game state as fast as possible (currently we use setImmediate to queue up the loop immediately, you could probably relax that if you wanted), updating the central state which will be sent on socket update, our server goes ahead and plows ahead updating "game state" (which in this case is just a loop ticker) outside of the socket i/o requests.

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
server.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log('listening');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('connected');
  socket.on('update', function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('update', state);
  });
});

var loopAsync = function() {
  setImmediate(loop);
}

function loop() {
  gameLoops++;
  var delta = Date.now() - last;
  last = Date.now();
  var currentState = {
    time: Date.now(),
    loopDelta: delta,
    loops: gameLoops
  };

  state = currentState;
  loopAsync();
}

var last = Date.now();
var gameLoops = 0;
var state = { time: Date.now(), loopDelta: 0, loops: gameLoops };
loopAsync();
```

Full working example can be found here: https://github.com/StrangeWill/qpexamplecode